# Python weird circumflex (^) issue in NAPTR query

Tags: python, dns, escaping, dig

I'm using Python2 to implement a server which provides NAPTR DNS answers using dnslib.

The forged answers are in the following format:

```
0.0.0.0.0.0.0.e164.arpa. 60 IN NAPTR  20 20 "u" "SIP+E2U" "!^.*$!SIP:0000@whatever.0.0.e164!" .
```

I use *dig* in order to perform the queries by using the following syntax:

```
dig NAPTR 0.0.0.0.0.0.0.e164.arpa @<server_ip>
```

The issue is that whenever the regexp part of the NAPTR record contains a circumflex (^), *dig* flags the retrieved packet as malformed:

```
;; Got bad packet: syntax error
```

If I remove the circumflex from the string, the query answer gets retrieved properly.
So it seems that the circumflex is being somehow misintepreted.
I tried to specify *regexp.encode('utf-8')*, but that didn't solve the issue. 
Any ideas?

Comment: Please reduce your program to the smallest possible program that demonstrates the error, and copy-paste that entire short program into your question. For example, [My server](http://ideone.com/TlMGnu), built from your description, works just fine on my PC. See [mcve] for more info.